# Can't rename a master page or edit using SharePoint designer 2013, although I have create it

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, development, master-page, custom-masterpage

I am working on a SharePoint online Team site collection. now the team site have the publishing infrastructure features disabled. Now i want to create a custom master page for my site collection. **and since i have the publishing infrastructure site collection feature is disabled, so i can NOT upload a new master page using the UI (Site setting>>Look and Feel>>Master page)**, so i decide to create the new master page using sharepoint designer.

To do so I did the following steps:-

- I login using an admin account (have full permission)
- Using SharePoint designer 2013 I copy the `seatle.master`.
- Paste it.
- Where a new master page named `seatle_copy(1).master`
- Now I tried to edit it using SharePoint designer , but I got this error:-

[image]

- Also when I try rename it , I will get this error:-

> Server Error : Access Denied

So I am not sure why I have the ability to create a new master page , but I can not edit, rename, check-out, check-in ,etc...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue occurs if this  option `Customizing Master Pages and Page Layouts` is disabled !

To check the value of master page customization is allowed on the current site collection try to run the following code

```
function getMasterPageAccess() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    oSite = clientContext.get_site();   
    clientContext.load(oSite);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, function() {
            var siteInfo = '';
            //The below line get the boolean value of  master page editing is allowed on this site collection
            if (oSite.get_allowMasterPageEditing())
                siteInfo = 'MasterPage customization: Allowed';
            else
                siteInfo = 'MasterPage customization: Not Allowed';
            alert(siteInfo.toString());
        }),
        Function.createDelegate(this, function(sender, args) {
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }));
}

function injectMethod() {
    getMasterPageAccess();
}
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(injectMethod, "sp.js");
```

Code Ref [Get Master Page Customization](https://gist.github.com/sksnips/a97d688e08f3fc12795f) in Browser console

If it's not allowed you can run this code in browser console

```
function enableMasterPageAccess() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    oSite = clientContext.get_site();

    //The below line helps to enables the master page access
    oSite.set_allowMasterPageEditing(true);

    clientContext.load(oSite);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, function() {
            var siteInfo = '';
            //The below line get the boolean value of  master page editing is allowed on this site collection
            if (oSite.get_allowMasterPageEditing())
                siteInfo = 'MasterPage customization: Allowed';
            else
                siteInfo = 'MasterPage customization: Not Allowed';
            alert(siteInfo.toString());
        }),
        Function.createDelegate(this, function(sender, args) {
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }));
}

function injectMethod() {
    enableMasterPageAccess();
}
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(injectMethod, "sp.js");
```

Code Ref [Enable / Disable Master Page Customization in Site Collection](http://www.ktskumar.com/2016/03/enableordisable-master-page-customization-site-collection/)

**Or use the following PowerShell Script**

To enable `Customizing Master Pages and Page Layouts` in **SharePoint online** by following the mentioned steps

1. Download and install [SharePoint Online SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038).
2. Download the [.ps1 file](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Enable-page-editing-when-30eaab53#content).
3. Open the file (you can do it also in NotePad)
4. Insert your data in these lines:

**PowerShell**

```
# Paths to SDK. Please verify location on your computer. 
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"  
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"  

# Insert the credentials and the name of the admin site 
$Username="admin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com" 
$AdminPassword=Read-Host -Prompt "Password" -AsSecureString 
$Url="https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/teamsitewithlibraries" 
$setting=$true
```

- Find on your computer where SharePoint.Clitent.dll and SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll libraries are located and insert the correct paths
- Instead of "admin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com" enter you username
- Instead of "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/teamsitewithlibraries" enter the name of the site collection where you want to change the setting
- If you want to ENABLE master page editing, skip the next line. If you want to DISABLE master page editing, change it to $false

  5. Run the script in Powershell (any module).
  6. At the end you should receive a confirmation message like this:

[image]

Ref for script [Enable page editing when master page editing has been disabled for this site](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Enable-page-editing-when-30eaab53#content)

Also, For **SharePoint enterprise** you can enable this option from the central administration > application management > select web application > general setting > SharePoint Designer > check `Enable Customizing Master Pages and Layout Pages` .

[image]

**Note:** After you `Enable Customizing Master Pages and Layout Pages` , if you tried to copy Seattle / Oslo Master Page , you should copy `*.Html` file rather than the `*.master` file.

Comment: hmmm.. so i need to do all these things !!.. now inside our sharepoint online center admin i can not find any option to access the application management,, the only option i get is a list of site collections .. when i access [link](https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com/) .. second point when i open the master page folder inside SP designer there is not any .html master pages . i only get .master & .preview .. not sure why .

Comment: also i am not sure how to locate the sharepoint.dll files.. now let say i install the SP online SDK to my pc .. then i do not have sharepoint dlls files is this correct ?

Comment: can u advice on these please?

Comment: for your first comment I mention this for SharePoint enterprise to be full answer and useful for all , for the second point , make sure you open the master page at the root site, not the current site , for how to locate the sharepoint.dll files once you install SDK you will find it at this installation path c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll

Comment: note @johnG , to make it clear in your case you should follow first steps for SharePoint online , but as I told you I mentioned for both versions to be useful for you and others because this error also appears in SharePoint enterprise  , please don't hesitate to tell me if you need any clarification

Comment: thanks for your explanation..  so seems i need to install the SDK and also the SP online management shell, is this correct ? as the SDK will NOT allow me to run the .ps1 file, it only install the required dll files to be used by the online management shell [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588) is this correct ? second question,, when sharepoint disable something there is always a reason behind it ,, so is there a reason why sharepoint disable modifying the master page for SP online,, while it allow it be defualt on SP on-premise ?

Comment: are Microsoft trying to say not to modify the master pages for SP online ? or we should not understand it this way ?

Comment: see my brother , once you have installed SDK that means you can work with SharePoint online objects  because the DLL now located in your PC , SDK not responsible to run .ps1 you will need to use windows PowerShell or SharePoint online PowerShell so try to run .ps1 with windows PowerShell if not working try to install SharePoint online management shell , this my proof https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161397.aspx to can use windows PowerShell with SharePoint online , but without SDK you can't reach

Comment: for second question , ,Microsoft recommends don't edit the default master page and if you need to do that try to create a custom master page and to do this you should have Customizing Master Pages and Page Layouts enabled , my suggestion to you now to check my updated answer to use JSOM rather than PowerShell script because it looks like you are not familiar with it

Comment: ok now i get your point with the SDK. but for customizing the master page, of course i will not directly modify the "_seatle.master_" master page, i will create a copy of the "_seatle.master_" and then apply the modification to the copy, and will keep the original "_seatle.master_" as is, but will not be the default master page..now as i mentioned using sharepoint designer i was able to create a copy of the master page (so this gives me an indication that i have the permission to create master pages), but i am unable to rename it, edit, delete , set it as defualt ,, etc

Comment: so i am not sure if the problem in my case is with the permission or it is somewhere else... thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48369/discussion-between-m-qassas-and-john-g).

Comment: @johnG not mean you can copy it you can edit it , based on the error message the Customizing Master Pages and Page Layouts is disabled :D , so i told you run the above code in console :) are you do this ?!

Comment: but why they are disabled at the first place ? i did not run the commands yet, because i was reading more about running shell commands again sharepoint online.. but could the problem be somehwere else? and will i face any drawback if i run your powershell command?

Comment: you know i investigate the issue more,, now you mentioned if i am using SP enterprise i can enable this option from "_ central administration> application management> select web application>general setting > SharePoint Designer >_" but in my case i was able to access this setting from the different location "_ Site Settings -> Site Collection Administration -> SharePoint Designer Settings_" so not sure if both settings are the same?  .. or your setting will apply it to the whole Web Application, while the other option will be for the current site collection only ?

Comment: Yes, my steps on Web application level , your steps on Site Collection level . By the way are you run the above code in Browser Consol to enable Customizing Master Pages and Page Layouts ? this is the last thing we stop in chat !!!

Comment: but i prefer to enable/disable the "Enable Customizing Master Pages and Layout Pages" option at the site collection level rather than at the web application level,so i can have more flexibility among other site collections. But I am not sure if this option is disabled at the web application level(as in my case) will i be able to enable it on the site collection level ?

Comment: In your case, it's SharePoint online, and my provided above JSOM code applies this option for site  collection level , please don't confuse with my solution for SharePoint on-prem ! as i told you I mentioned it to be useful for all versions ? are you need to remove it to avoid confusion !

Comment: ok thanks but my point is why i need to execute the JSOM code , if i can enable the "_Enable Customizing Master Pages and Layout Pages_"  from the UI by going to "_ Site Settings -> Site Collection Administration -> SharePoint Designer Settings_"?? is there any benefit of enabling this using JSOM compared to doing this from the UI ?

Comment: Dear, I suggest to you to do it with any comfortable method for you  but it's the same result meanwhile, I prove to you that the issue is related to disable Customizing Master Pages and Page Layouts and provide you how to solve it ? if you have another solution with the same result that not mean my answer is not correct !! finally it's up to you to accept my solution or other similar solution with the same result ! my role to tell you what's the issue and how to solve it , and you should appreciate my answer if it will solve your issue :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48465/discussion-on-answer-by-m-qassas-cant-rename-a-master-page-or-edit-using-sharep).

Answer (score 1):

From the description you added, I can tell you the basic idea why it is happening to you. In SharePoint 2013, the direct masterpage changes are restricted.

Follow below steps to make your masterpage:

1. You need to export `seatle.html` in your local drive.
2. Rename the file to your need.
3. Open `Masterpage gallery` in your site. Upload this HTML file.
4. In order to convert the HTML page to Master Page navigate to `Site Settings -> Look and Feel -> Design Manager`. click on Edit Master Pages
5. Click on link “Convert an HTML file to a SharePoint Master page”.
6. Select the HTML file from masterpage gallery.
7. Now you will be able to see your HTML in the list.
8. Click the ellipses and publish the page.

You will now be able to edit the masterpage using the designer.

Comment: but i do not have the Masterpage gallery link, as i did not activate the publishing infrastrucre feature